# Can we request SE developers to graduate our site?

Tags: discussion, support

Its been 811 days and we are still in BETA,of course there are many other sites which are in beta for 2000 days too but..

We have pretty good stats 3 of 5 having `Excellent` and other two in `Okay`

[image]

Can we put a request asking for graduation of our site? Waiting eagerly to see Magento SE in new and unique design.